# Adding a keydown event to a jQuery modal popup window with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created functions to create a Yes/No confirm window that popups with jQuery that I use in a .net project to confirm responses from the user. I have generated buttons that trigger functions depending on what you click on.

//load a specailized popup for confirming things in a localized manner
function popupConfirm(TitleKey, InstructionsKey, YesFunction, NoFunction) {

```
//create the service to give us the content
var agpc = new AjaxServices.AjaxPopUps();

//get the results and open the popup with the functions aligned
agpc.GetLocalizedStrings(new Array(TitleKey, InstructionsKey, "Yes", "No"), function (results) {
    var content = jQuery.parseJSON(results.toString());

    //get the buttons for confirm/or not
    var YesNoButtons = jQuery('<div></div>', { id: 'YesNoButtons' });
    var yesButton = jQuery('<a>' + content.Yes + '</a>');
    var noButton = jQuery('<a>' + content.No + '</a>');

    //add the event handlers
    yesButton.click(YesFunction);
    noButton.click(NoFunction);

    //set a nice pointer for mouse over
    yesButton.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    noButton.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    YesNoButtons.append(yesButton).append(noButton);
    //show the box
    openPopup("Non-JSON", YesNoButtons, eval('content.' + TitleKey), eval('content.' + InstructionsKey));

    });
}
```

Well now comes the difficult part. The company also wants keypresses to trigger the yes/no functions. An enter key should trigger yes and escape should trigger no. I have no real idea how I will do this with this type of setup.

You can ignore most of the code in there. It is to get localized strings from the server. It the adding the keydown() event that I can't figure out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not very hard to do, just try to custom-adjust and use the following cross-browser supported code.

If you need to catch the event keys (keys that are pressed on the keyboard) and do some actions:

```
$("#YourDialog").keypress( function(event) {  // when you do a key press inside of the element with ID YourDialog 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if( event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 27 ) { // catching event for clicking either enter key or escape key.
     $("#OkButton").trigger('click');
     // or $("#YourDialog").hide(); to hide your dialog.
    }
});
```

If on contrary you need to prevent the default key action you must use this code:

```
$("#YourDialog").keypress( function(event) {  // when you do a key press inside of the element with ID YourDialog 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if( event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 27 ) { // catching event for clicking either enter key or escape key.
     event.preventDefault();  // preventing the default action - so, in this case, when the enter or escape is pressed nothing will happen. Especially it's important when you want to prevent user from click some keys. 
     event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

You must catch the user event (the key that is pressed). Key Code 13 refers to the enter key and key code 27 refers to escape key. keyCode variable is universally will work in all browsers including Internet Explorer.

Please also refer here for complete [keyCode List](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

I hope this will work for you.